# How to move cursor to the end of a word document using VBA from the acces level

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, office-automation

My goal is to add formatted text at the end of a previously created word document form in acces using VBA.

I was able to add formatted text at the beginning of the document and add unformatted text to the end using : `InsertAfter Text`.

I tried moving the cursor in the word document to the end with the `.EndKey Unit:=wdStory`, and then enter the text. That function is running in the word macro perfectly. In acces I get the error : Bad parameters.
I have tried putting this function in different places, but none of them work.

My programe with `EndKey` in first spot:

```
 

Set wrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

wrd.Documents.Open "\\tp.corp\data\" & a & "\document.docx"

wrd.Visible = True

wrd.Documents("document.docx").Activate


With wrd.Selection

    .EndKey Unit:=wdStory 

    .Font.ColorIndex = 2

    .InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="yyyy-MM-dd", InsertAsField:= _

        False, DateLanguage:=wdPolish, CalendarType:=wdCalendarWestern, _

        InsertAsFullWidth:=False

    .TypeText Text:=" text "

    .TypeParagraph

    .Font.Color = wdColorBlack
```

And in second:

````
```Dim wrd As Object

 

Set wrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

wrd.Documents.Open "\\tp.corp\data\" & a & "\document.docx"

wrd.Visible = True

wrd.Documents("document.docx").Activate

wrd.Documents("document.docx").Selected.EndKey Unit:=wdStory

With wrd.Selection

    .Font.ColorIndex = 2

    .InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="yyyy-MM-dd", InsertAsField:= _

        False, DateLanguage:=wdPolish, CalendarType:=wdCalendarWestern, _

        InsertAsFullWidth:=False

    .TypeText Text:=" text "

    .TypeParagraph

    .Font.Color = wdColorBlack
````

Any hints or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Word constants, you've evidently set a reference to Word. In that case, you'd do better to take full advantage of that. For example:

```
Dim WdApp As New Word.Application, WdDoc As Word.Document, WdRng As Word.Range
With WdApp
  Set WdDoc = .Documents.Open("\\tp.corp\data\" & a & "\document.docx")
  With WdDoc
    Set WdRng = .Range.Characters.Last
    With WdRng
      .Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
      .InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="yyyy-MM-dd", InsertAsField:= _
        False, DateLanguage:=wdPolish, CalendarType:=wdCalendarWestern, _
        InsertAsFullWidth:=False
        .TypeText Text:=" text "
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack
        .TypeParagraph
    End With
  End With
End With
```

**Note:** there is no need for Word to be visible or for anything to be selected while any of this is being done.